# How to add a new line after writing a array of characters into a file using JAVA

Tags: java, file

After executing the following piece of code

```
 String content = new String("CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_" + code2 + "_" + countryCode2 + " = " + reason2);
    try {
      fileOutputStream.write(content.getBytes());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output is as follows:.

```
CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_64      _KE = Account Dormant-Refer to DrawerCONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_65      _KE = Wrong/Missing Account Number (EFT)CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_66      _KE = Wrong/Missing Reference
```

but i want it like

```
CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_64      _KE = Account Dormant-Refer to Drawer
CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_65      _KE = Wrong/Missing Account Number (EFT)
```

Pls suggest

Comment: Why don't you just add "\n" to the end of your string?

Comment: `How to add a new line ...` - Just do it. There's the "new line" character `\n`.

Comment: You don't need to put `new String(...)` around your strings.

Comment: Firstly make sure to add \n to your string, secondly you need to try opening your file using different viewer (like notepad++) see my answer, I have list another approach that you can use to write to file line by line.

Comment: it just appends \n to the string added and displayed . Tried this.

Comment: @Raf - I am using notepad++ only.

Comment: can you try adding **\r\n** and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see the rest of the code to tell you exactly what you should do, but you can simply use the character `"\n"` in your string.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve adding new line to a file in quite a few ways, here is the two approaches:

1. Add a \n to your String which would cause the remainder of the string to be printed in new line
2. Use PrintWriter's println method to print each string in new line

Also keep in mind that opening a file with Notepad might not recognize \n hence do not display the remainder of string in new line, try opening the file using [Notepadd++](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiR3fugrbDJAhXL7hoKHW0FDikQFggjMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnotepad-plus-plus.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNExci2YY1gy2cZYcnKLKfl2A9jWCg&sig2=Sxpl7YkeLMknj_X2MoWt3w&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d2s)

```
String code2 = "code12";
String countryCode2 = "countryCode2"; 
String reason2 = " \n I am reason."; 
String content = new String("CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_code_" + code2 + "_" + countryCode2 + " = " + reason2);

try {
     fout.write(content.getBytes());
     //don't forget to flush the output stream
     fout.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use PrintWriter as shown below:

```
String line1 = "This is line 1.";
String line2 = "This is line 2."; 

File f = new File("C:\\test_stackoverflow\\test2.txt"); 
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(f); 

out.println(line1);
out.println(line2);

//close the output stream
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) on top of the  output stream to write strings to files. This way, you'll be in control of the output character encoding.

Second, if you want to use your platform's line separator, you may use [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) which has `println()` methods using the correct newline character or character sequence.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, OUTPUT_ENCODING)
);

...

writer.println(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for this . Appending /n wouldnt solve any issue rather use BufferedWriter. BufferedWriter has a inbuilt newline mwthod to do the same. Thanks

Solution:

```
 try {
    File file = new File("Danny.txt");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream) );
    String content = new String("CONSOLIDATED_UNPAID_description_"+code2+"_"+countryCode2+" = "+description2);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.newLine();
    bw.flush();
    check = true;
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```